# Matching 2 Undirected Weighted Graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, algorithms, matrix, graph-theory

Consider 2 undirected weighted graph as shown in figure. Consider first graph as $G_1$ and second graph as $G_2$. Graph $G_1$ consist of vertices $V=\{F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4,F_5\}$ and graph $G_2$ consist of vertices $V=\{N_1,N_2,N_3,N_4,N_5\}$.

[image]

According to logic of my project we have to match vertices of 2 graphs as shown below.

\begin{align*}
    F_1 &= N_2\\
    F_2 &= N_5\\
    F_3 &= N_4\\
    F_4 &= N_3\\
    F_5 &= N_1
\end{align*}

These matching values are calculated manually by seeing values of diagonal elements of 2 adjacency matrices given below.

Adjacency matrix for 2 graphs are shown below.

```
     F1     F2    F3    F4    F5
 F1   3     4     3     1     4
 F2   3     5     3     1     4
 F3   4     3     3     1     4
 F4   3     2     3     1     4
 F5   3     4     3     1     5

      N1    N2    N3    N4    N5
 N1   4     3     2     1     4
 N2   4     3     3     1     2
 N3   4     3     2     1     2
 N4   4     3     2     1     1
 N5   4     3     2     1     5
```

How it can be done in matlab?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have unique values on the diagonal?

Comment: @Aaron  Ya diagonal elements are always unique in my case.

Comment: What does graph theory have to do with signal processing?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it’s a hot [new area of signal processing](https://dsiseminar.github.io/)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, Though this one is on the border, there are many applications to Graph Theory in Signal and Image Processing.

Comment: @Royi I don't see any application here.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I agree about this specific question. I still enjoyed solving it. Never thought about this nice problem.

Comment: @Royi Other people might enjoy solving it using other methods, and they cannot solve it if they cannot find the question. I, for example, found it accidentally because I subscribe to the tag Matlab

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I actually looked yesterday on all unanswered questions and stumbled this one. I added the `graph-theory` tag.

Comment: @Royi Though I subscribe to `graph-theory` tags on various SE sites, I am not notified when someone creates a tag.

Comment: @prash2, Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice question!

If we define $\boldsymbol{u} = \operatorname{diag} \left( \boldsymbol{G}_{1} \right) $ and $\boldsymbol{v} = \operatorname{diag} \left( \boldsymbol{G}_{2} \right) $ the the problem can be written as:

$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{ \boldsymbol{P} } \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{u} - \boldsymbol{v} \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{P} & \in \mathcal{P}
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$

Where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of permutation matrices:

$$ \mathcal{P} = \left\{ \boldsymbol{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d} \mid \boldsymbol{K} \boldsymbol{1} = \boldsymbol{1}, {K}_{i, j} \in \left\{ 0, 1 \right\} \right\} $$

Namely they have a a single non zero element per row with a value of 1.

Looking at the optimization term:

$$
{\left\| \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{u} - \boldsymbol{v} \right\|}_{2}^{2} = \boldsymbol{u}^{T} \underbrace{\boldsymbol{P}^{T} \boldsymbol{P}}_{= \boldsymbol{I}} \boldsymbol{u} - 2 \boldsymbol{u}^{T} \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{v} + \boldsymbol{v}^{T} \boldsymbol{v} = {\left\| \boldsymbol{u} \right\|}_{2}^{2} - 2 \boldsymbol{u}^{T} \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{v} + {\left\| \boldsymbol{v} \right\|}_{2}^{2}
$$

Now, since $\boldsymbol{u}^{T} \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{v} = \operatorname{Tr} \left( \boldsymbol{u}^{T} \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{v} \right) = \operatorname{Tr} \left( \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{u}^{T} \right) = \operatorname{Tr} \left( \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{W} \right) $ we can rewrite the optimization as:

$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{ \boldsymbol{P} } \quad & \operatorname{Tr} \left( \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{C} \right) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{P} & \in \mathcal{P}
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$

Where $ \boldsymbol{C} = - \boldsymbol{W} = - \boldsymbol{u} \boldsymbol{v}^{T} $.

The above is solved by the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).
In MATLAB it is solvable by [`matchpairs()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matchpairs.html).

The code is available at my [StackExchange Codes Signal Processing GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q16227` folder).

**Remark**: My solution assumes the correspondence you're after is the one which matches the diagonal of each adjacency matrix. So the solution I wrote above actually gives a better solution than yours. It maps `1 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 1`.